# Parse escaped comma in a csv file using PHP

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv, php-8.1

I'm trying to parse a csv file. But when trying to parse the following line, I'm facing an issue with an escaped comma.

```
<?php
$str = "19018216307,Public,\,k]'=system1-system2,20230914143505.5,1-050000,No";
$data = str_getcsv($str);
?>
```

Output:

```
<?php
Array
(
    [0] => 19018216307
    [1] => Public
    [2] => \
    [3] => k]'=system1-system2
    [4] => 20230914143505.5
    [5] => 1-050000
    [6] => No
)
?>
```

Let's consider the column value **\,k]'=system1-system2**. It is expected to be parsed as **,k]'=system1-system2**. But when processing the CSV file, PHP treats this as 2 columns and the result is like **\** and **k]'=@system1-system2**.

Expected output:

```
<?php
Array
(
    [0] => 19018216307
    [1] => Public
    [2] => ,k]'=system1-system2
    [3] => 20230914143505.5
    [4] => 1-050000
    [5] => No
);
?>
```

NOTE: The CSV file is a raw data generated by an external website. So I can't do anything with the csv file content. (For eg: putting column values in double quotes)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I think so. I really did the following workaround.

$str = str_replace('\,', '|comma|', $str);
$data = str_getcsv($str);
$data = array_map(function($v) {
 return str_replace('|comma|', ',', $v);
}, $data);

But I just want to make sure,  if there is any better way to tackle this situation?

Comment: That is not how escaping in CSV works; that external website is delivering you _garbage_. You won't be able to use `str_getcsv` in this directly, you will have to _somehow_ "fix" your input data first.

Comment: Your sample data does not even match the shown output - how did `system1\,system2` turn into `system1-system2`...?

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, that's my mistake. Just corrected it!

Comment: The escape character that `str_getcsv()` implements is only used to escape the enclosure character (double quotes by default) but your data seemingly uses it to escape the separator (comma by default). As already said, this is a very peculiar CSV dialect so you won't be able to use the builtin feature.

Comment: Replacing `\,` with something that will never occur in the data, and replacing it back in the column contents in the array afterwards, is the quickest way to go about this. The other alternative would be to see to it that you get the whole field content wrapped into double quotes, but the logic to determine where to insert those, would be more complex.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, that's what I did now. I used `|comma| ` to replace `\,`

Comment: @NikhilMohan, I'm unclear if your problem has been solved or not?

Comment: @NikhilMohan: Bad idea, what if the backslash is escaped with another backslash: `\\,` (or any even number of backslashes before the comma).

Comment: @ChrisHaas I have pushed my code, but need to test it with the new raw data. I will update here, when it is done!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for your strange "csv format":

```
$str = "19018216307,Public,\,k]'=system1-system2,20230914143505.5,1-050000,No";

$pattern = <<<'REGEX'
~(?nxx)
    (?# modifiers:
        - inline n: parenthesis act as a non-capturing group
        - inline xx: white-spaces are ignored even in character classes
        - global A: all the matches have to be contiguous
    )

    # pattern
    ( (?!\A) , \K | \A ) # not at the start with a commas or at the start without
    [^ , \\ ]* ( \\ . [^ , \\ ]* )* # field content (all that isn't a comma nor
                                    # a backslash, except escaped characters) 
                                           
    # final check
    ( \z (*:END) )? # define a marker if the end of the string is reached
~A
REGEX;

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $m) && isset($m['MARK'])) {
    $result = array_map(fn($s) => strtr($s, ['\\\\' => '\\', '\\' => '']), $m[0]);
    print_r($result);
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/WHOMg#v8.2.11)

If the format allows newlines in a field, add the modifier s. (i.e. `~As` at the end of the pattern or `(?nxxs)` at the start)

Comment: I was concerned about this and I tried your code. But it is not working if there are multiple lines in the csv file.

Comment: @NikhilMohan: This code is designed for one line (as in your example since you used the `str_getcsv` function). To make it work for a whole file you can use it like that: https://3v4l.org/M7tJP#v8.2.11